# Repeating gradient background not working in Internet explorer

Tags: css

I am using background repeating linear background, crossing lines on the image, the linear background is working in Chrome and in Firefox but not working in Internet explorer

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient( 136deg, #e3e0df00, #e3e0df00 12px, #d8d8da7a 0px, #d8d8da73 24px );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is not as good at beautifying the code as Chrome or Firefox, so even the missing white space could be the problem. In this case, I can only suggest you add `0px` to the first color that you defined like this:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient( 136deg, #e3e0df00 0px, #e3e0df00 12px, #d8d8da7a 0px, #d8d8da73 24px );
```